Javascript IF multiple arguments
I'm debugging an external js library code and I found this syntax:
if(argument1, argument2) { ... }

It is the first time I face more than one argument in an if block, what is its meaning?
I tried to understand how it works with some tests:
if(false,false,true) alert("TEST"); //this alert is fired!

and
if(true,false,false) alert("TEST"); //this alert is not fired!

And it seems only the last argument is evaluated.

It's pretty rare to see an if like this, but it's using the comma operator so those rules apply.

So the comma operator evaluates both of its operands from left to right and returns the value of the second operand. Im curious to know what are valid use cases for this unusual dynamic approach and how readable is this syntax?

@Sarkis not very readable. Not super useful when writing code, too. I struggle to think of a good reason to use it when manually typing (I occasionally use it out of lazyness for some quick code, so I don't have to expand out a simple arrow function, e.g . x => console.log(x), x + 1 but that's not for any sort of production code). But useful for minfying code. When is the comma operator useful?
